# How can i get a dominant frequency from data in Python?

Tags: python, fft, frequency, frequency-analysis

I'm trying to plot power-frequency graph of binary star system. My data consists of time(in day unit) and flux(normalized). SciPy fftpack is used. Then, i got `sci_flux` and `sci_freq`. While plotting graph, power is calculated by `20*scipy.log10(sci_flux)`. Also i want to get a dominant frequency to calculate period of a system but i couldn't. How can i get a dominant frequency?

```
time, flux = loadtxt('KIC011616594.txt', usecols=(0, 1), skiprows=0, unpack=True)

#-----SciPy-----#
sci_flux = abs(scipy.fft(flux))
sci_freq = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(flux.size, time[1]-time[0])

#-----Graph-----#
pylab.subplot(211)                          # graph of time series
pylab.plot(time, flux,'b.', markersize=1)

pylab.subplot(212)                          # graph of (frequency,power)
pylab.plot(sci_freq,20*scipy.log10(sci_flux),linewidth=1.0, linestyle='-', color='red')

savefig("ep2.png", dpi=300)     
pylab.show()
```

Comment: don't you simply need to find the maximum of `20*scipy.log10(sci_flux)` and its corresponding frequency?

Comment: Show us the image it saves.